# Making a certain coefficient of a generating function for partitions as small as posssible

Tags: nt.number-theory

Begin by writing the generating function for unrestricted partitions as follows:

(1+x+x^2+x^3+…)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)⋯= 1+p(1)x+p(2)x^2+...

Now change some of the coefficients from plus to minus.  In the resulting series what is the smallest that the coefficient of x^n can be?  (Don't change the sign of  any of the ones.)  By smallest I mean that it is negative and that the absolute value is  as large  as possible.  For odd values of the exponent n one can get a coefficient of -p(n).  What happens for even n?

For example: Changing some of the first few coefficients as follows

(1 - x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4 - x^5 + x^6 - x^7 - x^8) (1 - x^2 + x^4 + 
   x^6 - x^8) (1 + x^3 + x^6) (1 + x^4 - x^8) (1 - x^5) (1 + x^6) (1 +
    x^7) (1 - x^8) gives 1-x-2x^2+3x^3+x^4-7x^5+5x^6+5x^7-18x^8+...

The coefficient of x^8 is -18 and this is the smallest possible;  p(8)=22 and -22 cannot be obtained by any choice of signs.